# Color Relations / Getting the right hue for a color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

In the latest version of Adobe Illustrator, I am working on some icons, and want to change the color of one.

[image: color]

The green one I'm happy with. The doc color and the fold color go well together. But, what if I want to change the color to yellow, how can I figure out what the fold color would be on the yellow so that it matches the green?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I would:

Create a layer

Click the button `Create Sub Layer` and name it **PageLayer**

On the Sub Layer Create the shape with top right corner cut out:

[image]

Click the button again `Create Sub Layer` on top of the **PageLayer** and title it **Fold**

On the **Fold** Layer create the fold itself and color it with `K60`:

[image]

Place the **Fold** Layer over the **PageLayer**:

[image]

Make sure it is all selected and click `Align` top and right from the `Align Object`:

[image]

Select the **Fold** layer and go to `Transparency` and choose the options `Multiply` at `40%`:

[image]

and you should have this:

[image]

Ideally you will be targeting a darker Hue of the page color.  I hope this helps and is what you're looking for.  You could always change the color of the **Fold** layer to a darker black or lighter black to target the Hue you're after

Answer (score -1):

I would lighten the yellow a bit and then use that current yellow color for the fold.

Comment: That is fine, but you're just guessing correct? Is there a tool / method I can use to get it exactly right?

Comment: How does this answer, "How can I figure out what the folder color would be on the yellow so that it matches the green?"

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. That's my fault. Sorry about that. I would do what @Gramps said. I've used that method before.

Comment: @AliciaUhacz I would like to welcome you to GD but before you answer it would be a good idea to read the question.

Comment: @Gramps I did read the question, thank you, I misread what he was asking for and came by that honestly.